# No getSchemaSeparator() method. Java, hibernate 3.3.2

Tags: java, hibernate, methods, deprecated

I'm working in a project, and recently we have migrated from hibernate 3.0.1 to 3.3.2. After fixing library dependencies and code errors, I've encountered a problem, and the problem is that the method `getSchemaSeparator()` of `Dialect` class (`org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect`) seems to be deprecated and doesnt appear anymore in hibernate 3.3.2.

Here is the code line:

```
dialect.getSchemaSeparator()
```

I've googled my problem and searched here for any fix, but nothing found. It seems that there are no such method.

My question is if there any method that can substitude the `getSchemaSeparator()` method?

Comment: See here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=951247&sid=2571b5c2d2bb5fd6967633cf756cb25a

Comment: Oh, great, thanks :) It's strange that I didn't found that page by myself after hours of google searching... :)